# How to assign dynamic value to a dynamic inputs using jquery in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my code, its in loop of dates. I want to assign different dates dynamic values as user clicks on different buttons.

```
<input value="<?php echo $date_s['cale'];?>-veg" name="prefixed_date_item[]" id ="<?php echo $date_s['cale']; ?>" type="hidden" class='csscategorys'>
```

JS CODE :

```
function select_type(date_value,dish_type) {
    var str=date_value+"-"+dish_type;
    var newStr = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    alert(newStr);
    $("#"+date_value).val(newStr);
    //$('input[name="prefixed_date_item[]"]').val(newStr);

}
```

Comment: Can you explain your issue? Your question is not clear.

Comment: i have buttons in loop of different dates...likie veg and nonveg buttons for diffrent dates...when i click veg for that date button and nonveg for different date button it should assign it to that input which is hidden inside loop.Ans then i put that into array but the problem is its not assigning the value to input using th script i wrote

Comment: did u get that KinjalMistry

Comment: From where you are calling `select_type` function??

Comment: from thse buttons                                                                            <button class="veg active" onclick="select_type('<?php echo $date_s['cale']; ?>','veg');">VEG</button>                                                                                                
 <button class="non-veg" onclick="select_type('<?php echo $date_s['cale']; ?>','nonveg');">NON</button>

Comment: did u get it @KinjalMistry

Comment: Yes, now let me know whats your `<?php echo $date_s['cale']; ?>` value is? because if you are giving it with `/` it will not work in jQuery

Comment: its like              onclick="select_type('2017-02-03 ','veg');"

Comment: now @KinjalMistry

Comment: Then it will work.

Comment: but its not working

Comment: What the issue you will get?

Comment: its not taking id  $("#"+date_value).val(newStr); if i do it using name it assign that value bt my requirement is using id

Comment: Now am trying using this demo                                                                                                                                                           <input value="" name="prefixed_date_item[]" id ="check" type="hidden" class='csscategorys' >                                                                                                                                                                       $('#check').val(5);             But no use

Comment: try to print `$("#"+date_value)` and check what the result you will get? 
`console.log($("#"+date_value))` and check it in firebug console log, did you get any element or you just get blank object?

Comment: it gives date value but why its not assigning that id new value                  var str=(date_value+"-"+dish_type);                                                         var newStr = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');                        $("#"+date_value).val(newStr);